# ios detect a device collision with other ios device, possible?

Tags: ios, collision, hit

How to detect when user collides his iphone with other iphone? My app is running on both devices.
Both devices can establish a connection over a bluetooth/wifi/internet.

Comment: You are going to experiment a lot with this. Nothing is made. Just check the values got when the devices collide, and experimentally determine what is produced when this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest using a combination of these two:

- Accellerometer for impact (already mentioned)
- RSSI value from Bluetooth LE for proximity check

Answer (score 1):

You won't find an API for that for sure, so you'll have to build that yourself using sensor data of the iPhone. I guess the accelerometer is the most promising for this task.

The implementation isn't trivial however and you'll have to experiment a lot with the data that you receive. Maybe you even have to use some data mining techniques to reach your goal.

Comment: is there something like this on github? it's sad if no (

Comment: Not that I knew of unfortunately